# Inclement weather at destination airport during layover in a foreign country

Tags: air-travel, layovers, chinese-citizens

As many of you North Americans know, there is an upcoming winter storm hitting the Northeast soon (at time of writing). I am about to take a flight from Shanghai, China back to New Jersey, with a layover in Narita, Japan.

If I arrive in Narita and the second leg of my flight is delayed (possibly to the following day), will I be permitted to exit the airport? What would be the standard procedure for the airline? (In addition, what would happen if I had to stay overnight?)

*Additional information:*

I'm a Chinese citizen, leaving from Pudong International Airport, stopping at Narita, and finally arriving at Newark International. The first leg (Shanghai-Narita) is operated by All Nippon Airways, and the second leg (Narita-Newark) is operated by United Airlines. I am also a minor (under 18), but not considered as an unaccompanied minor, at least by United.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: @Neusser I am a Chinese citizen.

Comment: You'll probably need this: https://www.sleepinginairports.net/asia/tokyo_narita.htm :-)

Comment: Note that in some situations, airlines may actually refuse to let you board the first leg if they think there is a strong chance you may get stuck at the connection airport. Or they may reroute you. What class are you flying, and do you have frequent flyer status?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the site of Ministry of Foreign Affairs of Japan, China is not in the list of [countries for visa exemptions](http://www.mofa.go.jp/j_info/visit/visa/short/novisa.html#section2). This means that you need a visa to enter Japan, so you will not be allowed to exit the transit zone of the airport.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just an additional question (I should've clarified in the original post), what would happen if I have to stay overnight? Do I just sit in the airport?

Comment: Yes, I think so. @Jerrybibo

Comment: Aw, this is going to be a tough trip. Thanks again for the clarification.